# $\left|\int_{A \cup B} f d\mu \right| \le \left|\int_A f d\mu\right| + \left|\int_B f d\mu\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on a measurable space $X$ and let
$$f : X \to \mathbb{C}$$
be a measurable function.
If $A$ and $B$ are measurable subsets of $X$, is it true that
$$\left|\int_{A \cup B} f d\mu \right| \le \left|\int_A f d\mu\right| + \left|\int_B f d\mu\right|?$$

**Attempts.** If $f : X \to [0, \infty)$ then I think that the answer is yes since we know that
$$\varphi(E) := \int_E fd\mu$$
is a measure on $X$ so the result follows by subadditivity. I'm not sure how to generalize this to complex-valued functions.

Comment: This probably fails. Try to find an example where the RHS vanishes but the LHS does not.

Comment: @PhoemueX Right. For example, $f(x) = \sin x$, $A = [0, 2\pi]$, and $B = [\pi, 3\pi]$ is a counterexample. Thanks!